# Automatic re-login with async calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, network-programming

I have two async calls to the server. Call A authenticates a user and returns a session token. Call B gets data from the server. Call B needs the session token from call A so that the server accepts the request and returns the data.

After 10 minutes the session token expires and the server refuses to return data to call B. In this scenario we would have to do call A again to re-authenticate and get a new valid session token that we could use for call B.

The problem I face is that I would like to automate this and that I have no idea how to implement it with a clean design. I would like to implement it that way, that if call B receives a "session expired" from the server, that it would start the async call A and restarts itself with the new session token provided from call A. Is something like this possible with the tools provided by Objective-C and the iOS Frameworks?

Comment: Nothing documented. You will probably need state flags (BOOL expired for example) to detect the need to re-authenticate. I probably would have used a single recursive message with flag testing.

Comment: I would recommend to read [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA), especially the chapter "Cookie Storage" and all chapters about authentication. The course of actions depends whether you are using a `NSURLSession`, a `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLDownload` object for the underlaying network request, and it depends how the session token is handled. If you handle that as a Cookie, you probably don't need to add much to your existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), you would create a subclass of AFHttpClient that knows how to perform both operations. In the implementation for callB, check if you get the invalid session response from the server and manually callA, then in its completion delegate callB again.

For calling `callB` after you have manually re-authenticated you'll probably want to capture the parameters to `callB` - if it's only a couple pieces of data, local variables would work fine. If that gets unwieldily, you can get tricky with the runtime and [record the NSInvocation](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/construct-nsinvocation-for-any-message.html) of your initial `callB` and execute it again later; basically your `callB` method would be swizzled/proxied to check if the session is valid.

Comment: I use RestKit which is based on AFNetworking and I already have the callA and callB implemented. Including the detection code if a session is expired. I know that if callB detects a session expired that I simply could call the method with callA in it. But my problem is how would call A "rerun" the complete callB after the session token got back including all the parameters methodB got called with? You write something about "completion delegate". Could you explain with more details what you mean? I think there is my misunderstanding.

Comment: Updated answer to include details of capturing message

Comment: Thanks RyanR. I did not know NSInvocation but this solution seems to be very promising. As far as I understand it, I would be able to save the method call to run B with all the arguments into a NSInvocation object and pass that to callA. callA could invoke the NSInvocation after a successful re-authentication and with that, callB would get rerun like nothing happened?

Comment: You got it. NSInvocation is quite powerful, should be a neat solution.

Comment: I've implemented this and it works great. Thanks again RyanR. There is one pitfall though. I had a hard time to create NSInvocations with the method arguments. Especially to correctly retain them. So for everybody who struggles with this, I eventually used a helper method `invocationWithTarget:selector:retainArguments:` to create the NSInvocations for me. I found this gem [here](http://www.jayway.com/2010/03/30/performing-any-selector-on-the-main-thread/)